# knockout data-bind date NaN/NaN/NaN

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I just tried to make a span with formatted date under foreach using knockout

I have this script

```
    Date.prototype.toFormattedDate = function () {
        var dd = this.getDate();
        if (dd < 10) dd = '0' + dd;
        var mm = this.getMonth() + 1;
        if (mm < 10) mm = '0' + mm;
        var yyyy = this.getFullYear();
        /* change format here */
        return String(dd + "/" + mm + "/" + yyyy);
    };
```

and in html i try this

```
<span class="form-control" data-bind="text: new Date(my_date).toFormattedDate() " />
```

my_date is a string date "2020-09-13T00:00:00"

but it always shows NaN/NaN/NaN

i tried to use moment.js but it gave me "Invalid date"

**Demo:**

```js
Date.prototype.toFormattedDate = function() {
  var dd = this.getDate();
  if (dd < 10) dd = '0' + dd;
  var mm = this.getMonth() + 1;
  if (mm < 10) mm = '0' + mm;
  var yyyy = this.getFullYear();
  /* change format here */
  return String(dd + "/" + mm + "/" + yyyy);
};

const formatted = new Date("2020-09-13T00:00:00").toFormattedDate();
console.log(formatted)
```

Comment: Your logic seems to work fine as a standalone module. Please see if you can create a demo for this which can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @palaѕн , it gives me a warning
 ```
The specified value "2020-09-13T00:00:00" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd".
```

Comment: The demo I have added in your post is working fine here, right?

Comment: yes , and i tried it i javascript file it works , but in view it shows NaN/Nan/Nan . weired!

Comment: Where are you modifying your Date prototype? (this is not best practice by the way)

Answer (score 1):

It's happening because `my_date` is an observable. `new Date(my_date)` will try to convert the observable to a date and it fails. So, get the value in the observable by using `my_date()` and use it in the `new Date()` constructor

```js
Date.prototype.toFormattedDate = function(){var a=this.getDate();if(a<10){a="0"+a}var b=this.getMonth()+1;if(b<10){b="0"+b}var c=this.getFullYear();return String(a+"/"+b+"/"+c)};

ko.applyBindings({ my_date: ko.observable('2020-09-13T00:00:00') })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<span class="form-control" data-bind="text: new Date(my_date()).toFormattedDate() " />
```

---

Another option is to create a [custom binding](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) for your date format. You could move all the date format code to the custom binding directly if you don't want to pollute `Date.prototype`

```
function customDateHandler(element, valueAccessor) {
  var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
  element.textContent = new Date(value).toFormattedDate()
}

ko.bindingHandlers.customDateFormat = {
  init: customDateHandler,
  update: customDateHandler
};
```

And use the binding in your span:

```
<span class="form-control" data-bind="customDateFormat: my_date" />
```

Here's a snippet:

```js
function customDateHandler(element, valueAccessor) {
  var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
  element.textContent = new Date(value).toFormattedDate()
}

ko.bindingHandlers.customDateFormat = {
  init: customDateHandler,
  update: customDateHandler
};

Date.prototype.toFormattedDate = function(){var a=this.getDate();if(a<10){a="0"+a}var b=this.getMonth()+1;if(b<10){b="0"+b}var c=this.getFullYear();return String(a+"/"+b+"/"+c)};

ko.applyBindings({ my_date: ko.observable('2020-09-13') })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<span class="form-control" data-bind="customDateFormat: my_date" />
```